# Transforming XYZ to WGS84/UTM Zone 18?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, utm, tile-map-service, xyz-tiles

I am using XYZ to Lat Long which I am then converting to UTM as I am unable to find XYZ to UTM implementation directly.So,in attached image there is distortion on boundaries which has particular pattern. I believe this behavior is because of converting Lat-Long to UTM and then using UTM co-od for further processing using gdal.

How do I calculate XYZ or TMS Tiles bounds in UTM directly instead of Lat-Long?

[image: Test DataSet]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: If the XYZ conversion led to a "square" or "rectangular" extent in lat/lon, the "tilt" you're seeing is fine. In a UTM zone, only the longitude line at the center of the zone is vertical. There is a tilt to latitude lines too, usually not at much as the longitude lines away from the central meridian.